# Clarification on PL/SQL JOINS in this Query

Tags: sql

I have a Query returning 377 Rows

```
Select Cm.Customerid,Cm.Customername,Ad.Addressid,Ad.Addressline1,
Stm.Statename,Ctm.Cityname,Dm.Districtname 
 From Crm.Customers Cm 
inner join Crm.Customeraddress Ad on Ad.Customerid=Cm.Customerid
Inner Join Ehis.Statemaster Stm On Stm.Stateid=Ad.Stateid
Inner Join Ehis.Citymaster Ctm On Ctm.Cityid=Ad.Cityid
inner join Ehis.Districtmaster dm on Dm.Districtid=Ad.Districtid
```

But if i add one more join to this (i.e)

```
Select 
Cm.Customerid,Cm.Customername,Ad.Addressid,Ad.Addressline1,
Stm.Statename,Ctm.Cityname,Dm.Districtname 
 From Crm.Customers Cm 
inner join Crm.Customeraddress Ad on Ad.Customerid=Cm.Customerid
inner join crm.agreements ag on ag.customerid=cm.customerid
Inner Join Ehis.Statemaster Stm On Stm.Stateid=Ad.Stateid
Inner Join Ehis.Citymaster Ctm On Ctm.Cityid=Ad.Cityid
inner join Ehis.Districtmaster dm on Dm.Districtid=Ad.Districtid
```

My query is not returning any rows. Is there any Problem in using inner join for statemasters,city n district masters. Pls clarify the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear to be with `statemaster`, `citymaster` or `districtmaster`, as these are in your original query that returns data.

The additional line (below) looks to be the culprit.

`inner join crm.agreements ag on ag.customerid=cm.customerid`

Presumably there are no records on the `agreements` table with a matching `customerid` on the `customers` table.

To prove that is the case, you could change that line to

`left join crm.agreements ag on ag.customerid=cm.customerid`

If you get your 377 records back, then you'll need to check the data in `agreements`.

Comment: @**richaux** :Yes I found that 'agreement' table doesnt have data of stateid matching with 'customer' table..so deadlock is solved as of now.